# Можно ли глобальную переменную удалить функцией?

Tags: python

В 1 функции обозначил переменную глобальной, в другой функции этой программы эта переменная должна удаляться, в голову пришло только это

```
def func():
    global var
def del_func():
    del var
```

Но это не работает, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: если вам понадобилось удалять глобальную переменную, значит вам не нужна глобальная переменная. Объясните для чего вы использовали глобальную переменную и вам, скорее всего, подскажут как обойтись без нее

Comment: В эту переменную записывается информация от разных пользователей, поэтому она должна быть общей, и не инициализироваться для каждого отдельного человека, а удаление переменной с этой информацией - функция для человека с специальными правами

Comment: это не объясняет необходимости использовать глоб. переменную. Переменные можно и лучше педедавать в функции в виде параметров.

Comment: @FMasluna, если вам помог ответ, то отметьте его галочкой. Так другие пользователи сайта увидят что на вопрос уже дан ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё один вариант удаления глобальной переменной:

```
def func():
    global var
    var = 0

def del_func():
    globals().pop('var')
```

Переменная удалится из глобальных. Но тут деструктор вызовется скорее всего после завершения del_func (надо позвать человека с дисассемблером чтоб это проверить).

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но для этого в той функции, где вы её удаляете, вам её тоже нужно объявить глобальной. И надо эту переменную вообще создать сначала. Директива `global` не создаёт переменную, она только объясняет интерпретатору, где ему искать переменную с таким именем, если она вдруг встретится.

```
def func():
    global var
    var = 'test'

def del_func():
    global var
    del var
```